# Javascript redirect that breaks back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to many answers on StackOverflow with `location.replace(URL)` you could redirect your user while keeping the page in the back button history.

I'd like to do the opposite, so I'm using `location.href = URL` but I'm still experiencing the correct working of the back button: why is this?

Also, using `location.replace()` in Chrome and IE10 seems to leave the back button intact as well. Please note that I'm not redirecting with `location.replace("http://...")` but with `location.replace("/page.html")`

I want to redirect my user from a page to a configuration wizard, while inside the wizard the user should not be able to go back and forth between the pages: instead, pressing "back" should redirect it to the original page, outside the wizard.

One solution would be to load the pages of the wizard via AJAX and inject them with [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). We've already developed most of our web app pages this way but for this particular part the AJAX solution has been neglected by server side developers (go figure!).

What can I do?

Answer (score 8):

You've got them the wrong way round. `location.replace` replaces the current page in the browser history. `location.href` advances to the page.

See here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: What can I do about location.replace in IE8 - is it working too? Thanks for your help, will test now! :)

Comment: Yes, it's always been this way so you can be assured it's compatible with all older browsers (that run JS)

Comment: location.replace() is not breaking the back button in Chrome. I'm still able to go back...

Comment: There's something else at play then as it works perfectly for me, and that is the way it's always been.  If I open the console on this page and do `location.replace("http://www.google.co.uk")` and then click the back button, I don't get this page - I get the one prior.

Comment: I've created an HTML with location.replace("/hello") in a setTimeout. As I open it with Chrome or IE10 I get redirected to an error page. As I hit the back button, I get back to the page with the redirect.

Comment: I've just done that on this page and it did as I described.  I'm not sure why you're having this problem.  This is the whole reason for the replace method - see the URL I've added to my answer.

Comment: I understood now... If you replace() with an http link it works. If you do it with a "/page" link it wont work. Unfortunately, I need the /page link...

Comment: It works fine for me either way.  I tried your `/hello` example.  They're exactly the same thing, using `http://` or not does not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout to the beforeunload event at MDN: [Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload)